# Does “foreign religious obligation” = “Takruvas Avodah Zarah”?

Tags: halacha, money, avodah-zarah

Background: There is a verse in the Christian scriptures (Luke 6:30) that, when read out of context, implies that a follower of *osso ha’ish* should give anything anyone asks for. I had heard an urban legend that anti-missionaries have used that against Jews for J——s types.

I was accosted by some Christian missionaries proselytizing in Midwood this morning and decided to try this prank. The fellow (not Jewish) said, “I’m not giving this to you to induce you to change religion; I’m giving this to you to obey the will of J——s.”

Now I have a $20 bill in my pocket, but may I spend it?  Is this *Takruvas Avodah Zarah*?

Comment: CYLOR..........

Comment: @SethJ, I most certainly will.

Comment: Maybe they liked your initials... :)

Comment: I wonder if it would have been permissible to ask them for all of their missionary materials, and then deposit the stuff in the nearest dumpster?

Comment: (As a note: such an interpretation would be out of context indeed...)

Comment: @IgnatiusTheophorus, please elaborate. While the intent, implied or otherwise, may not have been for this concept to apply in such a situation how does the "context" effect the issue?

Comment: @Yirmeyahu, if I understand correctly, IgnatiusTheophorus is referring to my original post; the NT verse I pointed to has to be read out-of-context to arrive at the interpretation I gave.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon is quite correct. I was referring to the passage in the NT.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon, out of curiosity, what is the correct context? (Summarize, please, don't quote 'Avodah Zarah here.)

Comment: @Seth J: The context is an instruction from Jesus to "love your enemies". Personally, I think the fellows in the story applied the text exactly correctly.  Of course, by asking for something on the basis of this verse, one would self-identify as an enemy (which may or may not be the intention). This is no answer, but if you ask (and take) money in this way, I think it would be dishonest to not use it in _some_ fashion.  Perhaps giving it to a favorite charity would satisfy the moral conundrum.

Comment: @JonEricson, I don't think the OP is concerned about any _moral_ dilemma. It's not like he stole it; the guy gave it to him. He's concerned with the religious implications of benefiting from money obtained not illegally or immorally, but in an exchange in which the giver stated he was giving it to him in the name of idolatry.

Comment: @SethJ, your understanding of my question is correct. I had no moral dilemma about taking advantage of a verse-out-of-context: most of his missionary text were using the tactic of verse-out-of-context.

Comment: @JonEricson, I actually met the fellow on the street a few days after posting this, and he also pointed out that my initial request was based on taking the verse out of context. (IIUC, Luke 6:30 in its proper context means he should not have asked for the return of the money once he realized he hadn’t been under any obligation to give it to me; and in fact he did not ask for the money.)

Comment: I know better than to attempt an answer in the religious question: I'm way out of my depth!  I had @Dave's suggestion in mind when writing my comment.  In purely human terms, it seems unethical to waste such a gift.  (I thoroughly enjoy the question.  I hope it gets an answer.  ;-)

Comment: Would this question apply equally to anything received in a Christian hospital?

Comment: I heard that there's a rabbi who goes to Jews for Jesus sermons and asks the lecturer in public for something he's carrying based on this verse. (I don't know who this rabbi is.)

Comment: @IsaacMoses, presumably not: the concern mentioned about using the mission hospitals in 1800’s Jerusalem stemmed from (perceived) missionary activity rather than the motivations behind the healing. And that seems a good direction for discussing the _halachik_ aspects of my question.

Answer (score 6):

Takruvas Avodah Zarah it surely isn't - unless you're an idol. :-) Even if the money was set aside to be given to an idol, it would be OK. Source: [Rambam](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1407.htm) in הלכות עבודה זרה פרק ז:כא

We had a case in the Mishna ([Beitza 3:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h27.htm)) of a Rav who refused to accept a gift from a non-Jew. When asked why, he answered that it was to spite the non-Jew (and not because of Hilchot Shabbat, the subject under discussion there, IIRC.)

But otherwise there is no problem using a gift received from a non-Jew. We even accepted certain Korbanot from them. [הלכות מעשה הקרבנות פרק ג](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/8503.htm)

The closest related Halacha that I recall is the prohibition of doing business with idolaters around their Holidays. The reason being, that they go and thank their deities. See [הלכות עבודה זרה פרק ט](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1409.htm)

As a general rule, there's a prohibition to cause others - even idolaters - to mention the name of their gods. [הלכות עבודה זרה פרק ה](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1405.htm)

So while the money may be good, the "trick" caused another [unrelated?] prohibition, and therefore should/may not be repeated.

Comment: None of the sources you quote seem to discuss giving the gift leShem (for the purpose of) Avoda Zara. Only gifts given by worshipers of Avoda Zara

Answer (score 3):

Seems forbidden to me.

The Rambam lists [51 mitzvot](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1400.htm) ([English](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912348/jewish/Avodah-Kochavim.htm)) regarding Avoda Zara. Number 31 is "not to derive any benefit from anything used in service of an idol" (my translation).
He elaborates in [Laws of Avoda Zara 7:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1407.htm) ([English](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912365/jewish/Chapter-Seven.htm)):

> עבודה זרה עצמה, ומשמשיה, ותקרובת שלה, וכל הנעשה בשבילה--אסור בהנאה, שנאמר "ולא תביא תועבה אל ביתך" (דברים ז,כו).  וכל הנהנה באחד מכל אלו, לוקה שתיים--אחת משום "ולא תביא תועבה אל ביתך", ואחת משום "ולא ידבק בידך מאומה, מן החרם" (דברים יג,יח).

As you see, *Takrovet* and *Mishamsheha* are two separate categories. While I agree that the money is definitely not *Takrovet*, they are giving you the money in order to follow the gospel which seems to be exactly what is meant by "used in service of A"Z."